# MediaElement.Source throws 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement, video-player

I'm writing a WPF application and I have a **MediaElement**-Property called **VideoPlayer** in a class called **ViewmodelVideos**.

When I say

```
ViewModelVideos.VideosPlayer.Source = new Uri(text);
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
```

I can't figure out why thats not working. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

"text" is a valid url which I can put into my browser and it works. No https, simple http://...

Comment: Having a MediaElement in a view model sounds odd. A view model should not have any view elements. Besides that, my guess is that you're doing the call outside the UI thread. What is the exception message?

Comment: @Clemens Can you tell me how to get the exception message? The programm doesn't stop, only the exception message `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll` appears in the output window. There is no try catch around it either.

Comment: @Clemens the remark about doing the call outside the ui thread seems spot on. Do you know how to set the source from outside the ui thread?

Comment: `ViewModelVideos.VideosPlayer.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ViewModelVideos.VideosPlayer.Source = new Uri(text));`

Comment: @Clemens you sir, jsut made my day. please wrtie it as an answer.

Comment: Don't forget to move the MediaElement out of your view model.

Comment: And where? code behind?

Comment: You may probably simply bind a MediaElement's Source property to a view model property of type Uri.

Comment: But then I can't start and stop playback by buttons, can I? It's a videoplayer with GUI-buttons to control playback. (Also, do you want to write your answer as an answer, so I can accept it?)

Comment: Then your view may perhaps subscribe to a dedicated event in your view model. For an answer, I would prefer to close the question as duplicate, because this has been asked too often. However I can't, because I already voted to close as off-topic. You might simply delete it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens comment did the trick:

The problem was, that I was doing the call outside the UI thread.

Solution was

```
ViewModelVideos.VideosPlayer.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ViewModelVideos.VideosPlayer.Source = new Uri(text));
```